# old-style cast for a complicated long

Tags: c++

Can anyone point to where/how I can get rid of old-style-cast warning for the long variable `latency`?

```cpp
time_t timestamp;
suseconds_t timestamp_us;
int tod;

#define ONE_MILLION 1000000
#define USEC_IN_DAY (long)8640000000

long latency =((timestamp % SEC_IN_DAY )*ONE_MILLION+ timestamp_us - long(tod * ONE_MILLION) + USEC_IN_DAY) % (USEC_IN_DAY);
```

```
xxxx.cpp:130: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast]
       latency =((timestamp % SEC_IN_DAY )*ONE_MILLION+ timestamp_us - long(tod * ONE_MILLION) + USEC_IN_DAY) % (USEC_IN_DAY);
```

The warning message points to `timestamp_us`, but not sure if that is the problem. Should I be using `static_cast<long>`? If so, where? Everything I try doesn't remove the error.

Putting `reinterpret_cast<long>` in front of `timestamp_us` seems to clear up that part (i think), but using `static_cast<long>` for `long(tod * ONE_MILLION)` doesn't work

Any ideas?

Comment: Your posted code doesn't compile. You haven't defined `SEC_IN_DAY`. Also, you should use `const`/`constexpr` instead of `#define` for constants in C++.

Comment: I assume the warning is coming from your use of a C-style cast in `#define USEC_IN_DAY`. You should use a numeric literal type specifier instead of an inline C-style cast.

Comment: sorry #define SEC_IN_DAY 86400

Comment: The easiest way would be to make the literals longs: `#define ONE_MILLION 1000000L`, `#define USEC_IN_DAY 864000000L`, and remove all the `long()` casts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the `USEC_IN_DAY` macro. The `(long)` is an old style cast.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `#define` macros are inlined into your code: they aren't "intelligently" handled by the compiler because they're processed by the preprocessor, not the compiler.

So this:

```
#define USEC_IN_DAY (long)8640000000

long latency = ( ( timestamp % USEC_IN_DAY ) * ONE_MILLION + timestamp_us - long( tod * ONE_MILLION ) + USEC_IN_DAY ) % ( USEC_IN_DAY );
```

Is seen by the compiler as this:

```
long latency = ( ( timestamp % (long)8640000000 ) * ONE_MILLION + timestamp_us - long( tod * ONE_MILLION ) + (long)8640000000 ) % ( (long)8640000000 );
```

...which is chock-full of C-style casts.

---

If you're writing in C++, **then write in C++**. Don't let idioms and conventions from C creep into a C++ project. Just because a good chunk of pre-C99 C is mutually-intelligible with C++ doesn't mean it's a good idea to copy 'n' paste from C into C++.

If you use global `const` values then you can avoid these problems entirely. [You should also use the `L` suffix so the compiler knows the literal value is intended to be a `long`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) value.

```
const long ONE_MILLION = 1000000; // Though you should not give these UPPER_CASE names as that's still reserved for #define macros.
const long USEC_IN_DAY = 8640000000;
const long SEC_IN_DAY = 1000000;

int main()
{
    time_t timestamp;
    suseconds_t timestamp_us;
    int tod;
    
    long latency = ( ( timestamp % USEC_IN_DAY ) * ONE_MILLION + timestamp_us - long( tod * ONE_MILLION ) + USEC_IN_DAY ) % ( USEC_IN_DAY );    

    return 0;
}
```

That said, complex single-line expressions are hard to read. Your code is much easier to understand if you use named variables to hold intermediate results:

```
long getLatency( time_t timestamp, suseconds_t timestamp_us, int tod ) {
    
    const long one_million =    1000000L;
    const long usec_in_day = 8640000000L;
    const long sec_in_day  =      86400L;
    
    //

    auto a   = ( timestamp % usec_in_day ) * one_million;
    auto b   = tod * one_million;
    auto c   = a + timestamp_us - b + usec_in_day;

    auto latency = c % usec_in_day;
    return latency;
}

int main()
{
    time_t timestamp; // Note that you cannot assume that `time_t` always represents timestamps using the Unix timestamp system.
    suseconds_t timestamp_us;
    int tod;
    
    //
    
    long latency = getLatency( timestamp, timestamp_us, tod );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Dai. I didn't realise: "It's because #define macros are inlined into your code: they aren't "intelligently" handled by the compiler because they're processed by the preprocessor, not the compiler." Someone else wrote this bit of code and i didn't like the warnings it was giving.

Comment: "It's because #define macros are inlined into your code": no it isn't. It is because there really are lots of old-style casts.

Comment: @user207421 I wrote that because (from first-hand experience) people new to C and C++ who come from more modern languages make many assumptions about how compilers work (for example: that the `(long)` cast in the `#define` would *not* be inlined in the actual compiled program code). The objective of my answer was to tackle OP's underlying misconception or misunderstanding which I believe is the "real" cause of the OP's problem - regardless of the specific technical detail you're referring to.